# Tool to create uml models in java - Developing practice

Tags: java, modeling

I should clarify my question here, I want to practice my programming skills and I want to develop a simple diagram modeling tool, something where I can move objects with the mouse, drag and drop, but I have no idea where to look to learn this kind of things in Java.

I hope my question is clear, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not the place to ask such questions. We are here to help you if you have a problem with a certain part of your already-written code. Perhaps there is another site in the StackExchange network that is suited for your question. (Someone help me out here with a suggestion)

Comment: Try the [JavaFX tutorials to learn graphics techniques in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) and the [Oracle JavaFX forums for questions such as this](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/java/javafx/javafx_2.0_and_later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at a desktop application or a web based application?

For a desktop based application, you should start looking a swing or javafx to get started with the basic ideas and the move along.

For web application, it is a bit more complicated for a beginner. I suggest you to start with spring examples and then implement the front end with the help of some javascript library. Like JQuery, Dojo and Draw2D etc.